# How to annotate a queryset with a new field of information from a related model?

Tags: django, annotations, django-annotate

I have a model where a `Vehicle` table has more `Wheels` tables. I am trying to display in a single field the information of the vehicle and of the first wheel in the related Wheels table. I have seen that the `F` function might be useful but I cannot find the correct configuration for it to work. The tables are related through another field named `colour` which is declared as a foreign key in the `Wheels` table.

```
    class VehicleListView(ListView):
        template_name = 'vehicle.html'
        queryset = Vehicle.objects.all()

        queryset = queryset.annotate(wheel1_name = F('Wheels__wheel_name'))

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context
```

I would like the line

```
    queryset = queryset.annotate(wheel1_name = F('Wheels__wheel_name'))
```

to return a list of the first wheel name for each vehicle so I can iterate through it and show it in a table.

```
models.py

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vehicle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Wheels(models.Model):
    wheels_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  db_column='color')
    wheel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: I edited the question and added the models

Comment: @Stevy do you know how I could solve this?

Comment: You want your API to return a list that contains each `Vehicle` with the first related `Wheels` object right?

Comment: @Stevy yes, that's what I'd like

Comment: @Stevy, thanks, your solution is almost exactly what I need. I am actually using the data as {{x.wheel}} in an html template, is there an option of getting the same result without serialization that requires REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed your code a bit, setup the database, created 2 `Vehicle` objects with each 2 related `Wheels` objects, so 4 `Wheels` objects in total.

I added a function that [queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) for the first related `Wheel` object for a certain `Vehicle` object.

```
# models.py

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vehicle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # this function returns a slice of the resulting queryset which contains
    # the first related Wheels object for each Vehicle object
    def get_first_wheels(self):
        return Wheels.objects.filter(color=self).order_by('wheels_id')[:1]


class Wheels(models.Model):
    wheels_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    wheel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I used [Django serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to serialize the data. To get the first related `Wheels` object I used a [`SerializerMethodField()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) that calls the `get_first_wheels()` function in `models.py` like this:

```
# serializers.py

class WheelsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wheels
        fields = ('wheels_id', 'color', 'wheel_name')


class VehicleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_wheel = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_first_wheel(self, model):
        qs = model.get_first_wheels()
        return WheelsSerializer(qs, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ('vehicle_id', 'vehicle_name', 'color', 'first_wheel')
```

I changed your view a bit and used a [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead.

```
# views.py

class VehicleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VehicleSerializer
    queryset = Vehicle.objects.all()
```

I went and used a [`DefaultRouter()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) to register the endpoint like this:

```
# urls.py

from rest_framework import routers
# import ViewSet here

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'vehicles`, views.VehicleViewSet, base_name='vehicle')
```

Then I ran the following commands:

- `manage.py makemigrations`
- `manage.py migrate`
- `manage.py runserver`

I created 2 `Vehicle` objects with each 2 related `Wheels` objects.

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/vehicles/` in my browser it returns all the `Vehicle` objects with their first related `Wheels` object like this:

```
[
    {
        "vehicle_id": 1,
        "vehicle_name": "BMW",
        "color": "Blue",
        "first_wheel": [
            {
                "wheels_id": 1,
                "color": 1,
                "wheel_name": "BMW1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": 2,
        "vehicle_name": "Ferrari",
        "color": "Red",
        "first_wheel": [
            {
                "wheels_id": 3,
                "color": 2,
                "wheel_name": "Ferrari1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```